# Simpleaudio not running form terminal on Raspberry

Tags: python, audio, python-import, playback, raspberry-pi4

I am trying to run simpleaudio on a RaspberryPi4 without much success.
This is my script:

```
import simpleaudio as sa

wave_obj = sa.WaveObject.from_wave_file("path/to/file.wav")
play_obj = wave_obj.play()
play_obj.wait_done()
```

I can run it from the editor, it plays back the wave file. However, when I try to run it from the terminal, I keep getting the following error message

```
ImportError: No module named simpleaudio
```

I am using the  `sudo python test.py` command to run it. I have also tried it using  `sudo python3 test.py`
but I keep having the same problem.

Does anyone have any idea what could be the issue?

Thanks in advance for any help! :)

Comment: You likely installed the library into a virtual environment, but aren't in the virtual environment when you try to run the script. Double check for that.

Comment: when you run in editor then you can check `print( sys.executable )` to see what version it uses. And then you can use the same version in terminal.

Comment: Thank you for the comments! Everything was installed in the same environment under python 3. In the end uninstalling and then re-installing Simpleaudio was what solved the issue.